# ion-content method scrollToPoint not working on Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am following this [ionic5](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content) and [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/master/src/demos/api/content/index.html) documentation in order to programmatically scroll my page to a point. Following is the code

```
getContent() {
      return document.querySelector('ion-content');
}

scrollPage() {
      this.getContent().scrollToPoint(100,100);
}
```

Method `scrollToPoint()` is not doing anything. Is there another way of calling this method?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Can you post your full HTML and JS? This method works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can not apply methods at item obtained by selector. You must be select this ion-content with `@ViewChild` and can use methods:

`@ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;`

`content.scrollToPoint(100,100);`

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is having trouble with this using **VueJS + Ionic 6**. I got it working by storing the $ref in my data() on mounted(). Don't forget to add the ref attribute like so: `<ion-content ref="myContent">`.

```
data() {
  return {
    myCustomContent: null
  };
}
```

In your mounted()

```
mounted() {
  this.myCustomContent = this.$refs.myContent.$el;
}
```

Your method:

```
scrollFunction() {
  this.myCustomContent.scrollToBottom(500);
}
```